# PrintWriter Encoding Problem

Tags: windows, character-encoding

I´m developing a netsh thread that keeps netsh open so I just have to call it once.

Everything worked fine until I tried my app in a Spanish-Windows enviroment...

netsh tells me that it can´t find the interfaces I´m specifying on the commands and I´m pretty sure that the cause of this is because some of these interfaces names have accents...

So, I´m guessing this is a encoding problem...

my code looks like this:

```
private netshOutStream =  new BufferedOutputStream(netshProcess.getOutputStream());
private PrintWriter netshWriter = new PrintWriter(netshOutStream, true);
Scanner fi = new Scanner(netshProcess.getInputStream());

public void executeCommand(String command) {
        System.out.println("Executing: " + command);
        String str = "";
        netshWriter.println(command);
        fi.skip("\\s*");
        str = fi.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the other constructor and give him the right character set for the process:

```
public OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)
```

Can you give the logging output of what netsh *receives* ?

Comment: Hi... !!!

For example:
"Executing: int ip set address "Conexión de área local 2" static 6.4.4.4 255.0.0.0"

and str value is:
"Interfaz especificada no v lida Conexión de área local 2."

which means: invalid interface, like that interface didn´t exists, and I´m 100% sure it exits, look at a ipconfig output of my machine:

Adaptador Ethernet Conexión de área local 2          :

        Sufijo de conexión específica DNS :
        Dirección IP. . . . . . . . . . . : 5.4.4.4
        Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
        Puerta de enlace predeterminada   :